# Form controls selection problem/bug on Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, visual-studio-2019, selection

I experience a strange bug on Visual Studio 2019, and I want to know if you can reproduce it too on your project.

Usually, if you click on the form and then start dragging the mouse, you will see a selection dashed rectangle that shows which controls on the form will be selected. The problem I see is that if my Form is pretty large, for example 1900x995, then when I click and drag with the mouse on the right bottom area of the form, the selection rectangle is cut in the middle.

See this picture for better understanding:

https://i.ibb.co/xzZLfsD/VS219-Form1-Selection-Bug.jpg

If my calculations are right, then it looks like the selection rectangle is cut at about 1570x846 (if the Left-Top of the Form is 0x0).

To reproduce it, open a new project of type:

C# Windows Forms App (.NET Framework) A project for creating an application with a Windows Forms (WinForms) user interface.

**Important note:** It's not happening if I choose C# "Windows Forms App (a project template for creating a .NET Windows Forms (WinForms) App)".

Set the Form size to 1900x995, then click any point on the bottom-right area of the form, and start dragging with the mouse to the bottom right corner of the form.

Do you see the selection dashed rectangle cut out in the middle?

Please let me know, I want to know if it's happening only on my installation, or is it a bug in the Visual Studio 2019 itself.

If you have other version of Visual Studio, for example VS-2017, or VS-2020, please check it also. Maybe this problem occurs in other versions too and not only in 2019 version.

Thanks.

Comment: I am using VS 2019 and have the same bug when I use form size like you did 1900X995

Comment: Very interesting... I hope that this bug will not influence the performances of my application, for example if some of the controls are located over this area... I hope that this bug is only visual during design time.

Comment: Confirmed here as well. It seems the bottom and right border of the drag rectangle disappear when they reach the 1602 on the x axis and the 858 value on the y axis. And if you start the drag to select from a position above these value the drag rectangle is totally hidden

Comment: The problem happens whenever root document designer has scrollbars, no matter what the form size or your screen resolution is. For example, even if you have a Form having 500x500 size, if you resize VS so that the designer vertical scrollbars appear, then scroll down and try to draw the selection rectangle, the rectangle will be clipped. It's a bug in designer, which is probably because of not considering the display rectangle or the wrong positioning of the transparent drawing surface. It doesn't have any impact on the run-time of your app.

Comment: I tried VS 2019 and VS 2022. The bug is for Windows Forms designer for .NET Framework projects, but not for .NET (Core, 5, 6) projects.

Comment: @ Reza Aghaei Thanks!